# Why did a DNS A record change break my responsive site?

Tags: css, a-records

I built a responsive site at hollamentors.com, which displays as intended on mobile (scaled correctly). I set up a DNS A record at hollamentors.org which points to the IP of the server where hollamentors.com is located. I've verified it has the latest code by making updates via FTP to the site on the hollamentors.com hosting. But the site on hollamentors.org loads on both iOS Chrome and Safari as a downscaled desktop site, as though I didn't have the

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

tag in the `<head>` of the HTML, which I do, otherwise the hollamentors.com site would load the same way. On desktop Chrome at a resolution of 767px or narrower, the CSS media queries work as expected, and it looks as expected.

Is there any reason that a DNS A record would cause this behavior? Or is there anything else that I'd need to verify?

I thought for a second that I hadn't set up the A record correctly, but I just uploaded a change to the hollmentors.com server, and the *content* of it is reflected on hollamentors.org.

Using `nslookup`, I can see that the domains show two different server IPs:

```
nick@young-birches:~/projects/holla_mentors$ nslookup hollamentors.org
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   hollamentors.org
Address: 184.168.131.241

nick@young-birches:~/projects/holla_mentors$ nslookup hollamentors.com
Server:         127.0.0.53
Address:        127.0.0.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   hollamentors.com
Address: 142.44.244.232
```

But that doesn't explain why the markup would be the same at both domains, but the sites would display differently on an iOS device. (I don't have an android device to test with.)

Comment: http://hollamentors.org/ is loading http://hollamentors.com in a frameset. Is this intentional? Might be safari blocking unsecure http loads in a frame.

Comment: Did some research, If i were to guess you probably picked the wrong record type which would (URL Iframe) since there's a frameset in your page, And because pages are rendered according to the top most frames any nested changes will be ignored

Comment: @ZohirSalak The frameset is the issue. If you add that as an answer, I'll mark it correct and upvote.

Comment: Just as long as you don't delete the question, the answer will be available for future researchers :)